# WPF drag and drop in listbox with preview shadow of where it will be dropped

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, listboxitem

I have written a kanban board user control where I can drag and drop some cards from one column to the other (listboxes / listboxitems) and I have used the component "https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop" to do this. Now I want to add a new behavior: show a preview shadow where the card will be dropped like in the animated gif in attachment:
[image: drop shadow of card being inserted]

The animated gif shows the DevExpress component doing this. Instead of using DevExpress I would want to use another open source component, extend the gong-wpf-dragdrop or do this myself.

Has someone already done this or know of a component doing this? If not do someone has a strategy to do this?

- I have tried with adorners, but the adorners are in another layer and do not make place in the listbox for being displayed (maybe I am doing something wrong)
- The next thing I am trying right now is to add some temporary dummy element to the listbox, but to make it work seems rather complicated and needs a lot of code (maybe I am overcomplicating this thing)
- Do someone have better ideas of strategies or components or elements to use to make it work like in the animated gif?

I am astonished to not have found more on this topic on Google. Does everyone do such things with DevExpress or Telerik? Or has nobody posted an open source solution until now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I finally have implemented is the following:

- I added a hidden bottom and top shadow to each card contained in the listbox in XAML (attribute: "Collapsed").
- I have added a dependency property to manage the visibility of the bottom or the top shadow
- I have created a custom drophandler with following capabilities:

  - do not show shadow if dragged element and next one is hovered
  - show shadow when another element is hovered (top when top half is hovered, bottom when bottom half is hovered)

If someone is interested by the final solution/code please register your interest as a comment and I will provide it. If someone has a better idea of how to solve this problem, I am also interested.

[final application animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKfPR.gif)

Comment: It would be very cool if you can publish your solution as public, so all other can see if there is a better solution. So I'm interested to see your solution.

Comment: Solution was posted in my last comment on [GitHub - gong-wpf-dragdrop
 issue 148](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop/issues/148) as KanbanExample.zip. Please note that it was a specific solution for my problem and project.